# OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

**Tensorflow 1.3 Windows 7, Python 3.6**

I'm running into this error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 3, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

I've look at  similar thread:

[OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_5_shuffle_batch_1/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894815/outofrangeerror-see-above-for-traceback-randomshufflequeue-5-shuffle-batch)

[OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, current size 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224327/outofrangeerror-see-above-for-traceback-fifoqueue-1-batch-fifo-queue-is-cl?noredirect=1#comment71671935_42224327)

[OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099109/outofrangeerror-randomshufflequeue-2-shuffle-batch-random-shuffle-queue-is-c/46122109?noredirect=1#comment81625717_46122109)

Tried the solutions listed (excepted the annotation one, which I don't understand)

Here is my code:

```
#more testing tfrecords
```

### Creating TFREcords

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import cv2


#Gather image paths

DIR = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\DATA\IMAGE_2'

images = [os.path.join(DIR, image) for image in os.listdir(DIR)]

# len(images) is 41




def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

tfrecords_filename = 'testing_2.tfrecords'

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_filename)

for image in images:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)


    feature ={'train/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}



    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

### Loading TFREcords into Batches

```
#absolute path
tfrecords_filename = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\Transfer Learning Tutorials\testing_2.tfrecords'


with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string)
               }

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_filename],num_epochs=1)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [299, 299, 3])

    images = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image], batch_size=3, capacity=12, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for batch_index in range(2):
        img  = sess.run([images])
        print(img.shape)
        img = img.astype(np.uint8)
        for j in range(6):
            plt.subplot(2, 3, j+1)
            plt.imshow(img[j, ...])
            plt.show()
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

If needed I've uploaded the images as a zip file onto my github:

https://github.com/moondra2017/Testing_Cat_classifier_Tensorflow

labeled as IMAGE_2.7z

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and it was caused by the num_epochs=1 parameter (that I incremented to my actual number of epochs).

See this post: [TensorFlow random_shuffle_queue is closed and has insufficient elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050071/tensorflow-random-shuffle-queue-is-closed-and-has-insufficient-elements/43370673)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before,but many answer is not well,finally I find the answer is that we should generate the queue before [with tf.Session() as sess:]  if we want use num_epochs.

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51852234/edit) button to update the answer with your desired change.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the mistake.

My saved dimensions were [300,300]

The dimensions I was trying to load were [299,299]

```
#Image = tf.reshape(image, [299, 299, 3])
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this problem is related to the error message you shown in the first post. It had to do with the queue not having enough elements.